# How can I fade in a class when I add it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, I have this code for my "site":

(this is a codepen link)
https://cutt.ly/kGFj7qi

When I press the dark mode button, it just switches to dark mode. What I would like to do is make it so that it fades to dark mode. If needed, I can use jQuery. Is there any way to do this without interfering with the other code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the body of the question itself.  [Third party sites are fine for supplemental purposes, but should not be the only way in which code is shared in the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/6831341).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are adding and removing classes, you can ask the browser to handle the `transition` for you. I tested this in your pend and it seemed to work but you may want to mess around a bit.

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

where we tell the browser to have some sort of `transition` between all states that it can. Some states don't allow for `transition` but colors should.

Comment: Wow, just copied & pasted this a few times in my code, and it worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad it could be helpful! Feel free to make it the `accepted` answer to your question if that is your thing!

Comment: @ClaytonTDM - For what it is worth, you probably shouldn't have to (and wouldn't want to) copy and paste it _"a few times"_.  Once should be enough.  The [`*` (universal selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) is quite powerful but also inefficient; it is absolutely fine to use it for a some specific use cases like this one, but you shouldn't needlessly replicate it in your code.  While you have some bundling that restricts it to a namespace, selectors are read right to left, so that doesn't remediate the added inefficiency.

Comment: I tried the answer with `*`, but it transitioned the text after the background had already finished changing. So what I did is I put `transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;` into the 3 classes that are fading. It seemed to work better than using `*`